# npm, nvm, node versions

Tags: node.js, nvm, nam

I've got myself into a muddle trying to install a version of node under 6.0.0 in order to use the Domo Dev Studio.

I seem to have a version of node installed which isn't visible on nvm...

```
Bryonys-MBP:domo bryonymiles$ nvm ls
       v5.12.0
    v6.10.2
->       system
default -> v4.8.4 (-> N/A)
node -> stable (-> v6.10.2) (default)
stable -> 6.10 (-> v6.10.2) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)

Bryonys-MBP:domo bryonymiles$ node -v
v6.10.2
```

Any ideas?

Comment: in windows you need to run nvm in cmd as admin. Also you need to first install it as nvm and then use

Comment: do nvm use 5.12.0

Comment: Hi there.   Firstly I'm on a Mac - forgot to say - sorry.

Comment: Secondly - I've tried nvm use - it still gives a different version when I run node -v

Comment: Also, this might help"

Comment: nvm use 5.12.0
nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to "/usr/local"
Run `npm config delete prefix` or `nvm use --delete-prefix v5.12.0` to unset it.
Bryonys-MBP:~ bryonymiles$ nvm use --delete-prefix v5.12.0
Now using node v5.12.0 (npm v3.10.10)
Bryonys-MBP:~ bryonymiles$ node -v
v6.10.2

Answer (score 0):

(nvm maintainer here)

This can happen if you have a system node installed by brew, or, if your profile files are altering your PATH after nvm.sh is sourced.

Please file an issue on http://nvm.sh if this doesn't address your problem.